# Is there any hook to define new wp-config constant?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add new constant to `wp-config.php` file. But I don't want to add it manually, I just want to add it from my theme's `function.php` file.

Is there any action or filter that define new constant for `wp-config.php` file?

---

**UPD-01:**
The constans I want to add are:

```
define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'salt');
define('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE', true);
```

Comment: what constant are you trying to define?

Comment: Thanks @JamesJones. I just updated my question.

Comment: That's for https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/ right? Their instructions suggest defining the constant in `wp-config.php`.

Comment: Yes for that plugin. But as you suggested in answer and I've tested now, It's work fine for me in theme's `functions.php`. Thanks Again

Comment: If you absolutely need it to be in `wp-config.php` you can always consider appending it programmatically to `wp-config.php`. W3 Total Cache operates like that for instance. Downside and a thing to consider is one has to have write permissions on the file. And it may not always be in the same location. Also consider  using comments to encapsulate your addition with flags like `#start - custom constants` and `#end - custom constants` so you can easily find and replace the edits you spefically made, if we you want to remove them again (on activation and disabling of plugins or themes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, no. `wp-config.php` gets fired way before the theme `functions.php` file.

You can define a constant in your theme functions file easily enough with `define()` which can be used to overwrite a constant with the same name. The only problem is that WordPress defines **and** uses many of these constants before `functions.php` is called.